# MYSQL unique column based on other column

Tags: mysql, csv, unique, load-data-infile

I have a script where I load CSV files into a table with LOAD DATA INFILE REPLACE INTO command.

The files comes from different "stores" and all of the different stores goes into this table.

My question is how I can combine two columns which then becomes the unique, or maybe you have some other idea.

`storeid` = will NOT be unique for each row

`code` = will be unique for each store id

The goal is to load the csv files into the table and update the a row if something changed, based on storeid and code.
This all worked when I used different databases for each store and had `code` as unique, but now I want to have all stores in the same db.

Is combining the columns, e.g. 1+123 = 1123 = new unique the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to generate `code`? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: no `code` is a unique column for each store which exists in the csv file

Comment: I think you don't need to combine anything! You can use composite primary key instead. It does what you want for you!

Comment: @Pokies, could you explain how to use that?

Comment: It depends! What are the other columns except `storeid` & `code` ?

Comment: @Pokies, Well its an inventory register, with columns like stock, eancode, price and so on. Again, the code column is the only unique column per store

Comment: Since the `code` is unique for each `storeid`, it's better to get these 2 columns as a composite primary key (which you answered already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two primary keys as

```
CREATE TABLE stock(
  storeid int,
  code int,
  PRIMARY KEY (storeid , code)
);
```

which combines the two fields making them one unique, seems to work on my tests.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html:

```
If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. 
In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row.
```

you should create a unique index on your columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_of_the_index ON table_name (storeid, code);
```

Combined primary key on these two columns might also do the job.

Comment: Yes, but `storeid` and `code` will never be unique when I load them into the same table, `code` is only unique by storeid.

Comment: I suppose concatening store + code on the infile = unique is the only way

Comment: If code is unique per storeid, then you have unique pair (storeid, code) and that's what a unique index on pair of columns is for. Or am I missing something?